# Spring Cloud Dataflow Maven Snapshots - how to set update policy?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm developing a custom Spring Cloud Stream Processor and using a local Spring Cloud Dataflow Server (v 1.3.0.M1) to run it. As I'm still experimenting, I am using Maven to deploy snapshots to our internal remote repository, then registering them through the Dataflow shell:

```
dataflow:>app register --name myproc --type processor --uri maven://com.company.stream.processor:myproc:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I deployed a stream using `myproc`, and saw the info I expected in the logs. So I tweaked the processor, used Maven to rebuild/redeploy to remote repo, and confirmed the update indeed got to our remote repo.

I undeployed the stream, unregistered `myproc`, then re-registered and re-deployed. But, the server did not download the updated Snapshot version of the processor.

I don't want to have to manually remove snapshots from the local repo each time I register a new copy of the app. Is there a way to configure Maven properties in the application.yml so snapshots are always downloaded? I Googled for a list of Maven properties that may be listed in the .yml file but couldn't find one.

I have these Maven properties in the Dataflow server's `application.yml` configuration. I also ensured that the `settings.xml` file for the user running the local server has the updatePolicy set to 'always' but I don't think that's having any effect.

```
maven:
  local-repository: /tmp/scdf-artifact-repository
  remote-repositories:
    repo1:
      url: https://repo.company.com/maven2
      auth:
        username: user
        password: pw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. This is indeed a missing feature in Spring Cloud Deployer right now.

The RemoteRepositoryBuilder currently uses the default update policy which is daily. Created https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer/issues/229 to track this feature.

Meanwhile, if you want to work around, you can update the `spring-cloud-deployer` code to set the updatePolicy `remoteRepositoryBuilder.setSnapshotPolicy` [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer/blob/master/spring-cloud-deployer-resource-maven/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/deployer/resource/maven/MavenArtifactResolver.java#L116)

Comment: Thanks for creating the issue!

Comment: @user944849: This issue is now addressed and it is included in [1.3.0.M2](https://spring.io/blog/2017/09/18/spring-cloud-data-flow-1-3-0-m2-released#app-registry-and-maven-update-policies) release of Spring Cloud Data Flow. Please try it out and give us any feedback if you can. Thanks for using SCDF!

Comment: @SabbyAnandan, finally got a chance to try this and it works well! Thank you very much.